# ComputeRelative sum in EinsteinAnalytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, dataflow

In a ComputeRelative node I try to sum up the values of a grouping. I tried to use sum('parameter'), but it gives me the error

> Something went wrong while executing the computeRelative xxx node:
>   Unsupported function sum: sum('parameter')

In the Analytics SAQL Reference there is clearly a sum() function referenced.

As a next step I will try to use a loop to iterate through the child entries with the function next(), but I am afraid that this loop will also not work. Does anyone know the practice to use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a simple answer regarding the average calculation of a rollup: create a row-count field via computeExpression, use the augment node with a multiple lookup so that the sum of rows for the key(s) get counted and the rate gets summed up. Then divide the summed up rates by the row count.